# How can I migrate Azure Pay as you go subscription to Azure plan with zero downtime?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, subscription, azure-migrate

I found a way of migrating the resources first using Azure Resource Mover and then Switch the subscription. But still few resources cant be moved like Public IP (Standard SKU). This migration does have a downtime(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#validate-move).....But is there any way in which I can do this cross-subscription migration with Zero Downtime?

Searched the whole web but every solution says this Cross Subscription Migration is to be done using Azure Resource Mover ONLY.

Would be very helpful if I could get any leads on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

•   According to your situation, subscription migration does happen with no downtime for the migrating resources as stated in the official Microsoft documentation. Only write and delete operations are blocked during the migration activity. Screenshot attached below for reference.

[image: Azure Resource Mover]

•   Also, for migrating public IP addresses with standard SKUs, that cannot be done through Azure Resource Mover except for the basic SKUs public IP addresses. Please find the below links for reference. And as for migrating resources within Azure but between different subscriptions, currently only Azure Resource Mover is the only tool available since Azure Fabric is common between them.

Please refer below document links regarding moving the public IP addresses: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/move-across-regions-publicip-portal

Thanking you,

Comment: Thanks mate! But I am finding ways in which Standard SKU Public IP can be migrated.
The document says it is not possible with Resource Mover, But possibility with any other ways? that's what I am searching for!

Comment: You are welcome. Standard SKU Public IPs do not have any guaranteed availability zones due to which they cannot be associated with any Azure resource that are either zone redundant or are zonal, though this not the case with regions that offer availability zones. Also, you cannot downgrade standard SKU public IPs to basic one.

Comment: I spoke with the Microsoft people, Right now this transition to Azure Plan where they can switch the subscription type in the backend without losing any Standard IPs is not supported in India! Thanks!!